# php system(); function is losing args when run through cgi but not from cli

Tags: php, apache, bash, cgi, command-line-interface

When calling a php file which contains:

```
<?php system('/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/myScript.sh '.'myArg'); ?>
```

from cli through `php myScript.php` everything runs fine but when doing it through cgi, opening the url in the browser (apache in the background) `myArg` string gets lost.
Does anyone knows what could be failing?

PD: myScript.sh is just an

```
echo "$# $*" >> /tmp/foo.txt
```

so a tail /tmp/foo.txt shows everything works fine from cli but not from apache's cgi. Do I need any extra configuration in php.ini? Do i need anything special in my apache alias file? Is it boodoo?

Answer (score 1):

If your code is as you listed it above, `'myArg'` will not be lost. However, if you are populating the argument dynamically, you will need to ensure that you collect the argument in a way that works appropriately for the calling method.

When you execute the script via a browser, you can collect arguments via `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET`, or `$_POST`. When you execute the script via CLI, the arguments will be found in `$argv`.

If you have verified that you get the correct value for the argument, the next step is to check permissions. Ensure that the CLI user has permissions to execute the command with the argument specified.

Comment: Thx for the answer, by now myArg is just a string so it should work both for cli and cgi, isn't it?

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer but as i stated in the main post, myScript.php and myScript.sh both get executed without problems. myArgv is a php 'string' but i already know how to get arguments from cli/cgi. It's not a coding issue, i thing it could be something related to any kind of php cgi configuration or something relateed to the OS internals. Just to remark php myScript.php does the job fine while running it through the uri does exactly the same but with no arguments.

Comment: If PHP cli works so nice, why don't you invoke a CLI PHP from the CGI PHP?

Comment: Good, idea, will try it tomorrow. To invoke the cli php from cgi, should i run system(); call? exec(); one? thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user that runs apache has a shell in `/etc/passwd`. Default user is `nobody`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The user who runs apache as is www-data. myScript.php is owned by ubuntu user      cat /etc/passwd|grep -i www
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh

Comment: @user846226 Maybe your cgi file wasn't executed. Check file permissions of the file. (Anyway it could lead to 403 error...)

Comment: Hi, which cgi file are you talking about? :)

Comment: @user846226 I meant your php file that is about to run by cgi.

Comment: Well, but php is working fine. Which concrete file are you talking about, /usr/lib64/php5.3/bin/php-cgi? Which perms do you think it should have?